# Creating a Custom Data-Bound Web Control - How to Persist the Data Source?

Tags: c#, asp.net, custom-controls, sample, databound

It's been a while that I'm trying create a custom Data-Bound web control without success.

My problem is when the postback occurs the data source is not persisted. All the scarce samples that I found doesn't work either. Even on the [sample provided by Microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms366540%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) this problem occurs.

How can I persists the data source?

Someone knows better samples for me to study?